# Laravel Valet: "pugito" Project Returns 404 Not Found Error, but Newly Created Projects Work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

## Question:

I'm facing an issue with Laravel Valet that's leaving me puzzled. I have an existing laravel project named "pugito," which I've attempted to park and link using Valet. However, when I access "pugito.test," I consistently receive a "404 - Not Found" error.

## Problem:

I've successfully installed and used Laravel Valet for other projects on my macOS system.
Recently, I created a project directory called "pugito" and configured it to work with Valet by running valet park and valet link.
Despite following the same steps that have worked for my other projects, "pugito.test" consistently returns a "404 - Not Found" error when accessed in the browser.
Strangely, when I create a new folder (e.g., "aheer") and place a simple "index.php" file inside it, then park and link it using Valet, "aheer.test" works perfectly and displays the expected result.

## I have tried:

- Ensured that the "pugito" project directory contains all required files and configurations. Verified that Valet is running (valet start) and serving other projects without issues.
- Attempted to remove and recreate the "pugito" project, including re-running valet park and valet link. Checked Nginx configuration files for "pugito" and "aheer" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites for any discrepancies.
- To make it work, I attempted to switch between PHP versions using the valet use command valet use `7.3, valet use 7.4, valet use 8.2`).

## Environment:

- macOS (Version Monterey 12.6.1)
- Laravel Valet (Version  4.3.0)

## Need help:

- What could be causing the "pugito" project to consistently return a "404 - Not Found" error, while other projects created with similar steps work correctly?
- Are there any specific troubleshooting steps I can take to diagnose and resolve this issue with the "pugito" project?
- Is there a way to ensure that Valet recognizes and serves the "pugito" project correctly, as it does with newly created projects?

I appreciate any insights or guidance in resolving this puzzling issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what the reason for not being able to detect it is, I would request you do the following alternatives. Remove your project called "pugito", create a new dir with the same name, and just add `index.php`(See if it works and has nothing to do with the name). The second approach while cloning the project use a name other than `pugito`. At least it will solve your issue.

Comment: A 404 from the browser? A 404 from Laravel?

Comment: on browser i got like 404 - Not Found